# replacing NA by row with value in a list

Tags: r, replace, na

I have a table that looks kind of like this:

```
#   item  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
#1    1   2   4   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#2    2   1   4   5   6   NA  NA  NA  NA
#3    3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#4    4   1   2   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#5    5   2   3   4   6   7   8   NA  NA
```

and I have a list

```
list1<-11:13
```

I want to replace the NAs with the elements in the list by row and result should be like this:

```
#  item   1   2   3   4   5   6  7   8
#1    1   2   4   6  11  12  13  NA  NA
#2    2   1   4   5   6  11  12  13  NA
#3    3  11  12  13  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#4    4   1   2   6  11  12  13  NA  NA  
#5    5   2   3   4   6   7   8  11  12
```

I tried

```
for(i in 1:5){
  res<-which(is.na(Mydata[i,]))
  Mydata[i,res]<-c(list1, rep(NA, 8))
}
```

It seems to work with the table in the example but gives many warning messages. And when I run it with a really large table it sometimes gives the wrong result. Can anyone tell me what is wrong my code? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry didn't test it earlier.  Thanks @RichardScriven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the rows of 'Mydata' using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, create the numeric index for elements that are NA ('i1'), check the minimum length of the NA elements and the list1 ('l1') and `replace` the elements based on the minimum number of elements.

```
t(apply(Mydata, 1, function(x) {
           i1 <- which(is.na(x))
           l1 <- min(length(i1), length(list1))
            replace(x, i1[seq(l1)], list1[seq(l1)])}))

#  item X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
#1    1  2  4  6 11 12 13 NA NA
#2    2  1  4  5  6 11 12 13 NA
#3    3 11 12 13 NA NA NA NA NA
#4    4  1  2  6 11 12 13 NA NA
#5    5  2  3  4  6  7  8 11 12
```

Or as @RichardSciven mentioned, we can use `na.omit` with `apply` by looping over the rows

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) { 
        w <- na.omit(which(is.na(x))[1:3])
        x[w] <- list1[1:length(w)]
        x }))
```

Comment: Can also do `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {  w <- na.omit(which(is.na(x))[1:3]); x[w] <- list1[1:length(w)]; x }))`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you @RichardScriven

Answer (score 3):

You could do it all in one go using matrix indexing:

```
sel <- pmin(outer( 0:2, max.col(is.na(dat), "first"), `+`), ncol(dat))
dat[unique(cbind(c(col(sel)),c(sel)))] <- 11:13

#     item  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
#[1,]    1  2  4  6 11 12 13 NA NA
#[2,]    2  1  4  5  6 11 12 13 NA
#[3,]    3 11 12 13 NA NA NA NA NA
#[4,]    4  1  2  6 11 12 13 NA NA
#[5,]    5  2  3  4  6  7  8 11 12
```

Comment: In the output dat[5,8] should be 12 instead of 13.

Comment: @Yigreen - fixed now - needed to add a `unique()` in there.